# still getting Controller not a function, got undefined, while I'm not defining controller globelly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

Still getting the same ERROR `Argument 'AveragesCtrl' is not a function, got undefined` I've tried all the solutions provided by similar question on SO but with no luck , any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

```
<div >

    <div ng-controller="AveragesCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast">
        <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
        <td>{{actor.character}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

  </div>
```

JS

```
var myApp  = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.factory('Averages', function () {

        var Avengers = {};
        Avengers.cast = [
          {
            name: "Robert Downey Jr.",
            character: "Tony Stark / Iron Man"
          },
          {
            name: "Chris Evans",
            character: "Steve Rogers / Captain America"
          },
          {
            name: "Mark Ruffalo",
            character: "Bruce Banner / The Hulk"
          },
          {
            name: "Chris Hemsworth",
            character: "Thor"
          },
          {
            name: "Scarlett Johansson",
            character: "Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow"
          },
          {
            name: "Jeremy Renner",
            character: "Clint Barton / Hawkeye"
          },
          {
            name: "Tom Hiddleston",
            character: "Loki"
          },
          {
            name: "Clark Gregg",
            character: "Agent Phil Coulson"
          },
          {
            name: "Cobie Smulders",
            character: "Agent Maria Hill"
          },
          {
            name: "Stellan Skarsgard",
            character: "Selvig"
          },
          {
            name: "Samuel L. Jackson",
            character: "Nick Fury"
          },
          {
            name: "Gwyneth Paltrow",
            character: "Pepper Potts"
          },
          {
            name: "Paul Bettany",
            character: "Jarvis (voice)"
          },
          {
            name: "Alexis Denisof",
            character: "The Other"
          },
          {
            name: "Tina Benko",
            character: "NASA Scientist"
          }
        ];
        return Avengers;
    });



    myApp.controller("AvengersCtrl", function AvengersCtrl(Avengers) {
      var avengersCtrl = this;
        avengersCtrl.avengers = Avengers;
    });
```

Comment: Are the spelling mistakes present in your actual code? You misspell "Avengers" as "Averages" several times in the code shown here.

Comment: A good eye prevents average code :)

Comment: @GregL can u post this answer please ? that's solve my Issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no controller name `AveragesCtrl`

Your declared a controller name `AvengersCtrl`

Convert this

```
<div ng-controller="AveragesCtrl">
```

to

```
<div ng-controller="AvengersCtrl">
```